# GMail API Replying to Email Thread Using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, email, gmail-api

Dear All: I am sure many of you have discussed above topic multiple times after I am going through all the example and references I have managed to write the code to reply to same email ThreadID. But Unfortunately while I am responding to same ThreadID emails it's going as new email. I have attached my complete NodeJS Code help me to review and let me know where should I have to make the changes.

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const mailComposer = require('nodemailer/lib/mail-composer');
var program_name = process.argv[0]; //value will be "node"
var script_path = process.argv[1]; //value will be "yourscript.js"
var Sender_Email = process.argv[2]; //value will be "Sender Email"
var Receiver_Email = process.argv[3]; //value will be "Email To"
//var CC_Email = process.argv[4]; //value will be "Email Cc"
var Email_Subject = process.argv[4]; //value will be "Email Subject"
var Email_Template = process.argv[5]; //value will be "Email Template"
var ThreadID = process.argv[6]; //Path to attach the file
var Dec_Message_ID = process.argv[7]; //Encoded messageid
var FileAttachment = process.argv[8]; //Path to attach the file
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var day=dateFormat(new Date(), "mmm dd, yyyy HH:MM tt");
class CreateMail{

    constructor(auth, to, cc, sub, body, task, attachmentSrc = [FileAttachment]){

        this.me = Sender_Email;
        this.task = task;
        this.auth = auth;
        this.to = Receiver_Email;
        //this.cc = CC_Email;
        this.sub = Email_Subject;       
        var fs = require('fs');
        this.body = fs.readFileSync(Email_Template,{encoding:'utf-8'});     
        
        this.gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
        this.attachment = attachmentSrc;
    }

    //Creates the mail body and encodes it to base64 format.
    makeBody(){
        if(this.attachment.length>0){
        var arr = [];
        for(var i=0;i<this.attachment.length;i++){
            arr[i] = {
                path: this.attachment[i],
                encoding: 'base64'
            }
        }
        }
        let mail;
        //Mail Body is created.
        if(this.attachment.length>0){
            mail = new mailComposer({
                
                from: "Arthanareeswaran Chandrasekaran <arthaaadhi@visha.page>",                            
                //sender: this.me,
                to: this.to,                
                //cc: this.cc,
                replyTo: this.to,
                
                inReplyTo: "<CAO29sXBTxmE8M=xyTkdFfsrxB_Mdr5e6N6vXiijwTY9rn1kzpQ@mail.gmail.com>",
                references: "<CAF7UyHwMrUvy-ZLNyRfjDmX876EKi5T-oc8E_tXy2PwO19dZ_Q@mail.gmail.com> <CAO29sXBH_B0yG4G2p6tdW1uk_tq9qFXmc01CPO5HJopkvMbU4Q@mail.gmail.com> <CAO29sXCcHv4LQSumjht_5zHEYvSzjfYkGr+yCEHfjwnqRvt0=Q@mail.gmail.com> <CAO29sXCPAxzWG0dC-TKEi4cR3xM8hbHhSJQ0ZAhbXBjsp503oA@mail.gmail.com> <CAO29sXA2mpqx6qbEeB5ke_6kUTrwXsqMD8ku0Aq3E_R07YzCLg@mail.gmail.com> <CAO29sXBTxmE8M=xyTkdFfsrxB_Mdr5e6N6vXiijwTY9rn1kzpQ@mail.gmail.com>",
                
                            
                subject: this.sub,  
                html: this.body,
                
                textEncoding: "base64",
                attachments: arr
                
            }); 
        }
        else{
            mail = new mailComposer({
                
                to: this.to,                
                cc: this.cc,
                html: this.body,
                subject: this.sub,              
                textEncoding: "base64"              
                
            });
        }
        
        //Compiles and encodes the mail.
        mail.compile().build((err, msg) => {
            if (err){
                return console.log('Error compiling email ' + error);
            } 
        
            const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(msg)
              .toString('base64')             
              .replace(/\+/g, '-')
              .replace(/\//g, '_')            
              .replace(/=+$/, '');
            
            if(this.task === 'mail'){
                this.sendMail(encodedMessage);
            }
            else{
                this.saveDraft(encodedMessage);
            }
        });
    }

    //Send the message to specified receiver.
        sendMail(encodedMessage){
        this.gmail.users.messages.send({
            userId: this.me,
            resource: {
                                                                                
                raw: encodedMessage,                                
                threadId: ThreadID

            }

        }, (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                return console.log('GMail API - The API returned an error: ' + err);
            }

            console.log("GMail API Sending Email Reply from server:", result.data);
        });
        }

    //Saves the draft.
        saveDraft(encodedMessage){
        this.gmail.users.drafts.create({
            'userId': this.me,
            'resource': {
              'message': {
                'raw': encodedMessage,
                threadId: ThreadID
              }
            }
        })
        }

    //Deletes the draft.
        deleteDraft(id){
        this.attachment.gmail.users.drafts.delete({
            id: id,
            userId: this.me
        });
        }

        }

module.exports = CreateMail;
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Just sharing the input parameter I was using for the above code - node index.js "From Email ID" "To EmailID" "Re: Final Testing" "Report 4 - GMail.html" "ThreadID" "MessageID" "Attachment If any"

Comment: Hello there, in order to insert the message into the specified thread the `References` and `In-Reply-To` headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard. Moreover, the `Subject` headers must match as well. Can you confirm these?

Comment: Hello @ale13 Thanks for replying. Yes I have maintained the standards what is mentioned in RFC 2822. For Example these are the parameters I am passing, References - MessageID's , In-Reply-To - MessageID (Recent), Subject - Same Subject with Prefix "Re: " along with threadId = ThreadID. Once I turnoff Conversation View from Google Settings my emails are split into separate emails! Please help me to look into the code and let me know If any of the items I am doing wrongly. Thanks once again for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update your code to this and check that the `References`, `In-Reply-To` and `Subjects` headers match:

```
function replyToMessage(auth) {
    const gmail = google.gmail({
        version: 'v1',
        auth
    });
    const messages = [
        'From: NAME <email@email.com>',
        'To: NAME <email@email.com>',
        'References: <REFERENCE1> <REFERENCE2>',
        'In-Reply-To: <IN_REPLY_TO>',
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Subject: Re: SUBJECT',
        '',
        'BODY_OF_THE_REPLY',
        '',
    ];
    const message = messages.join('\n');
    const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(message)
        .toString('base64')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
        .replace(/=+$/, '');
    gmail.users.messages.send({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
            raw: encodedMessage,
            threadId: 'THREAD_ID'
        }
    });
}
```

Also please bear in mind that in order to see the replies accordingly, you will have to turn on the **Conversation View** from Gmail Settings.

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop):

> You can choose whether replies to emails are grouped in conversations, or if each email shows up in your inbox separately.

Hence, if this setting is not turned on, the email will show up separately in your inbox.

#### Reference

- [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: Hello Ale13: If we turn of the conversation only grouping email should go away right but if we are responding to same email through API it should come under same email right but I am getting as new separate email.

Comment: Hi Ale13: Thanks for your simplified code. In your code If I need to insert previous email while responding to ThreadID how I can achieve it. My apologies I am struggling to achieve this part can you help me to share the updated code to show how I can Insert old email message data while replying to the latest threadID. Kindly help me thanks

Comment: Hi ale13/ Anyone in the community please help me with the request I am badly stuck with this challenge of inserting the previous emails while responding gmail api.